# Tags not applied in Ansible included role

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I created a simple Ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: Install Icinga2 on Windows
      include_role:
        name: my.icinga2.role
        apply:
          tags:
            - install-icinga2
```

The role contains this tasks file:

```
---
- include_tasks: vars.yml
  tags: ['always']

- include_tasks: install.yml
  tags: ['install-icinga2-stack', 'install-icinga2']

- include_tasks: ido-install.yml
  when: icinga2_ido_enable == true
  tags: ['install-icinga2-stack', 'install-icinga2-ido']  

- include_tasks: configure.yml
  tags: ['install-icinga2-stack']

[...]
```

This is the result when I execute the playbook:

```
me@ansible:~/ansible$ ansible-playbook plays/icinga2-client-win.yml -i staging.ini --limit windows


PLAY [all] ***************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [my.windows.client]

TASK [Include variables for Icinga 2] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [my.windows.client]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [my.windows.client]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [my.windows.client]

TASK [Install Icinga2 Client and connect it to the master server] ****************************************************************

TASK [my.icinga2.role : include_tasks] ***************************************************************************************
included: /home/me/ansible/roles/internal/my.icinga2.role/tasks/vars.yml for my.windows.client

TASK [my.icinga2.role : Set default fact for mysql command] ******************************************************************
ok: [my.windows.client]

TASK [my.icinga2.role : Set fact for mysql command if auth params are given] *************************************************
skipping: [my.windows.client]

TASK [my.icinga2.role : Set Monitoring Plugins for old Debian Versions] ******************************************************
skipping: [my.windows.client]

TASK [my.icinga2.role : include_tasks] ***************************************************************************************
included: /home/me/ansible/roles/internal/my.icinga2.role/tasks/install.yml for my.windows.client

TASK [my.icinga2.role : include_tasks] ***************************************************************************************
skipping: [my.windows.client]

TASK [my.icinga2.role : include_tasks] ***************************************************************************************
skipping: [my.windows.client]

TASK [my.icinga2.role : include_tasks] ***************************************************************************************
included: /home/me/ansible/roles/internal/my.icinga2.role/tasks/install-Windows.yml for my.windows.client

TASK [my.icinga2.role : set_fact] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [my.windows.client]

TASK [my.icinga2.role : set_fact] ********************************************************************************************
skipping: [my.windows.client]

TASK [my.icinga2.role : Install Icinga 2] ************************************************************************************
changed: [my.windows.client]

TASK [my.icinga2.role : include_tasks] ***************************************************************************************
skipping: [my.windows.client]

TASK [my.icinga2.role : include_tasks] ***************************************************************************************
included: /home/me/ansible/roles/internal/my.icinga2.role/tasks/configure.yml for my.windows.client

TASK [my.icinga2.role : Check if Icinga 2 API are already activated] *********************************************************
[ This should not be included! ]

RUNNING HANDLER [my.icinga2.role : Restart Icinga2 on Windows] ***************************************************************
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/me/ansible/plays/icinga2-client-win.retry

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************
my.windows.client   : ok=10   changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Why the **configure.yml** role task file is included as it should be included only if I apply the **install-icinga2-stack** tag and I'm applying the **install-icinga2** one?

Further I realise that the **ido-install.yml** role task file is not included just because the **icinga2_ido_enable** variable is not `true` in this playbook (and its default is `false`), not because one of its tags is not applied (which should be what I want).

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The application of tags in [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role) means that tags

> will be applied to the tasks within the include.

In other words, the tasks in the included role will inherit the applied tags. It's a misunderstanding to expect that the applied tags will select the tasks. To select the tasks use `--tags` and `--skip-tags` on the command line, or in Ansible configuration settings, use the `TAGS_RUN` and `TAGS_SKIP` options.

One important fact is not mentioned explicitly in the documentation of [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role). The parameter [apply](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/include_role_module.html#parameters) tags works only if the whole task is `tags: always`. This is only shown in the [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/include_role_module.html#examples).

```yaml
    - name: Apply tags to tasks within included file
      include_role:
        name: install
        apply:
          tags:
            - install
      tags:
        - always
```

**Example**

Let's have role1 with the 2 tasks

```yaml
    shell> cat roles/role1/tasks/main.yml 
    - debug:
        msg: 'This is task 2'
      tags: task2
    
    - debug:
        msg: 'This is task 3'
      tags: task3
```

and a playbook

```yaml
    shell> cat play1.yml 
    - hosts: localhost
      tasks:
        - debug:
            msg: 'This is task 1'
          tags: task1

        - include_role:
            name: role1
            apply:
              tags: role1
          tags: always
```

If we run the playbook without any options all tasks are included

```yaml
    shell> ansible-playbook play1.yml | grep msg
        "msg": "This is task 1"
        "msg": "This is task 2"
        "msg": "This is task 3"
```

See other variations below

```yaml
    shell> ansible-playbook play1.yml --tags task1 | grep msg
        "msg": "This is task 1"
    shell> ansible-playbook play1.yml --tags task2 | grep msg
        "msg": "This is task 2"
    shell> ansible-playbook play1.yml --tags role1 | grep msg
        "msg": "This is task 2"
        "msg": "This is task 3"
    shell> ansible-playbook play1.yml --skip-tags role1 | grep msg
        "msg": "This is task 1"
    shell> ansible-playbook play1.yml --tags role1 --skip-tags task2 | grep msg
        "msg": "This is task 3"
```

**Note**. The listing of tags does not work as expected.

```yaml
    shell> ansible-playbook play1.yml --list-tags
    playbook: play1.yml
      play #1 (localhost): localhost    TAGS: []
          TASK TAGS: [always, task1]
```

(For the record: [include_role with apply tags does not work #52063](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/52063))

Comment: Thanks. So is it correct that the only way to select tasks into an included role and to execute only a part of it is applying variables?

Comment: Of course not. What would be the reason for the tags then? I've added an example.

Comment: Yes, I'm already using tags with --tags, but this is not what I want in this case, because I want an "automatic" playbook and force users to manually specify tags could deal to big errors.

Comment: I see. You don't get it with tags. It's either a command line or configuration. Next option might be [ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner).

Answer (score 3):

if we use `include_tasks` in a role --> then we have troubles with tags.
if we use `import_tasks` in a role --> all is ok

example:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.11.7]
```

a playbook: **admins.yml**

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - { role: admins}
```

a role:
./roles/admins/tasks/**main.yml**

```
---


- name:  ' create | Debian ' 
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks:  "Debian/create.yml"
```

/roles/admins/tasks/Debian/**create.yml**

```
---

- name: tag2
  debug:
     msg: "tag2"
  tags: tag2


- name: tag3
  debug:
     msg: "tag3"
  tags: tag3
```

lets list tags:

```
$ ansible-playbook   admins.yml  --list-tags

playbook: admins.yml

  play #1 (localhost): localhost    TAGS: []
      TASK TAGS: []
```

So we have troubles with tags.
Lets test it.

```
$ ansible-playbook   admins.yml  -t "tag3"

PLAY [localhost] 
TASK [Gathering Facts] 
ok: [localhost]
```

So zero tasks is accomplished.

lets change **main.yml**

```
---


- name:  ' create | Debian ' 
  ansible.builtin.import_tasks:  "Debian/create.yml"
```

Now we dont have troubles with tags:

```
$ ansible-playbook   admins.yml  --list-tags
playbook: admins.yml

  play #1 (localhost): localhost    TAGS: []
      TASK TAGS: [tag2, tag3]
```

Lets test it.

```
$ ansible-playbook   admins.yml  -t "tag3"

PLAY [localhost] 
TASK [Gathering Facts] 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [admins : tag3] ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "tag3"
}
```